# Exiting pthread causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, multithreading, join, exit

the code creates a segmentation fault and i don't know why...

```
pthread_t thread[1];

void Thread_without_function()
{
  int rc;
  rc = pthread_create(&thread[0], NULL, NULL, NULL);
  if(rc == 0)
    printf("Thread created.\n");
  else
    printf("Thread creating failed!(ret = %d)\n", rc);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  Thread_without_function();
  sleep(10);
  pthread_join(thread[0], NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

the following lines are the output:

```
Thread created.
Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a function( with the correct type ) to the `pthread_create`. Passing a null causes your segmentation fault.

```
void* Func( void* param )
{
    return param ;
}

rc = pthread_create(&thread[0], NULL, Func, NULL);
```

Comment: so the pthread_creating function doesn't notice that I'm trying to fool him, und returns a segmentation fault if I'm trying to do a thread_exit(), because the the code is trying to access the null pointer thread

Comment: @Momo In you implementation that would be the case. Documentation doesn't specify what happens if you pass a NULL, so don't.